# Have problem changing a value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array with 4 entries in each value - (1st name, last name, email, password). I am trying to format the password value so I can insert it into a database. As you can see, my results are not what I need. Why is this the result and what should I do to get my intended result? Thanks

```
php > $newlines[1][3] = "PASSWORD($newlines[1][3)]";  
php > echo $newlines[1][3];  
PASSWORD(Array[3)]
```

Comment: It looks like the ) and ] are transposed, but I'm still not sure what you are going for here.  is "PASSWORD" a function?

Comment: PASSWORD is a MySQL function I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
php > $newlines[1][3] = "PASSWORD($newlines[1][3)]";
                                                ^
```

But this not the only problem. You are accessing a multi-dimensional array and therefore, you have to put the array access into brackets `{}`. Otherwise, PHP would only subsitute the variable up to the first index (i.e. `$newlines[1]`). See also [**variable parsing**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

And as `$newlines[1][3]` is most likely a string, you should also put quotation marks around it:

```
php > $newlines[1][3] = "PASSWORD('{$newlines[1][3]}')";
```

or even better in my opinion:

```
php > $newlines[1][3] = "PASSWORD('" . $newlines[1][3] . "')";
```

Comment: Your third suggestion using concatenation did the trick. All of the others returned Array[3] when I wanted the string that was in the Array. Thank you.

Comment: @aliov: The problem was, that if you don't put `{}` around the variable, PHP will only parse the variable up to the first index (i.e. $newlines[1]) which is an array and therefore prints `Array`. You are right, even if you had no typo, you would have got the wrong result. Putting it into brackets should work, but personally I find concatenation much more readable anyway (it is easier to see, what is PHP and what not).

Comment: Thanks for the mini-lesson and the sound advice. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
"PASSWORD($newlines[1][3)]"
```

Should be

```
"PASSWORD({$newlines[1][3]})"
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a quotation mark placement problem. You want the result of the function Password() rather than the string "Password(-arguments-)".

Drop the quotations around the right side:

```
php > $newlines[1][3] = password($newlines[1][3]);
```

Comment: `PASSWORD()` is probably the MySQL function.

Comment: Ah, then in that case, the other answers should suffice as the transposition of bracket and parenthesis looks suspect.